# Erro ao chamar Forge

Tags: spring-mvc

Quando executo o Forge, ele me retorna o seguite erro:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by 
org.jboss.forge.furnace.impl.LoggingRepair$1 
(file:/Users/xxxxx/forge/forge-distribution-
3.8.1.Final/lib/furnace-2.27.0.Final.jar) to constructor 
java.util.logging.Level$KnownLevel(java.util.logging.Level)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
org.jboss.forge.furnace.impl.LoggingRepair$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further 
illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future 
release
```

Ja verifiquei os níveis de permissão das pastas do Forge e nada. Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Esta versão do JBoss Forge só roda com o JDK 8. A versão que suporta JDK 9 deve ser liberada em breve (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FURNACE-151).